# File input, String manipulation and output

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, replaceall

I am trying to take a file (e.g a txt file of code) that hasn't been formatted properly and then format it by pushing the brackets into the correct place using 'tab'. But with my code it doesn't print the first bracket. Note the first and last bracket must remain untouched. Thanks

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("NewStripped.txt"));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("FinalStripped.txt"));
    String line; 
    int count = 0;
    try{
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        count++;
        if (line != null){
          line = line.replaceAll("\\{", "\t{");
        } else if(line.contains("}")) {
          line = line.replaceAll("}","\t}");
        }                                       
        pw.println(line);
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      pw.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();          
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(count != 1)` will be true for all but the first line, which probably doesn't contain any closing brace.

Comment: Btw, wouldn't you want to add a number of tabs before a opening brace which corresponds to its level (zero-based), i.e. the brace on level 2 (having 2 "outer" braces) would be intended by 2 tabs? If so you might want to change your code and count open braces, i.e. on each opening brace increment the counter and decrement on each closing brace. Then add count-1 tabs before each brace.

Comment: Regex errors: line = `line.replaceAll("\\{", "\t\\{");`, `line.replaceAll("\\}","\t\\}");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the depth level.

```
int count = -1;
...
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.contains("{")){
        count++;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             line = line.replaceAll("\\{", "\t\\{");
    } else if(line.contains("}")) {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             line = line.replaceAll("\\}","\t\\}");
        count--;
    }                                       
    pw.println(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```